# Constrained minimization in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, minimization

I want to solve a constrained minimization problem and I am asking for some help on how to structure the code.

I understand that `fmincon` is what I should use by playing with the argument `@mycon` but I am struggling in adapting it to my case. Any suggestion would be extremely appreciated.

These are my files (`a` and `b` are predefined parameters):

1. `f1.m`

   ```
   function [y1, y2, y3]=f1(x1, x2, a)
   ...
   end
   ```
2. `f2.m`

   ```
   function w1=f2(x1, x2, y2, y3, b)
   ...
   end
   ```

Problem that I want to code:

> min `y1` w.r.t `x1`, `x2`
>   
> such that  `y1<=w1`

Comment: A simple concrete example may be useful to make it runnable, see [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`fmincon`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) as follows:

```
x = fmincon(@(x) f1(x(1), x(2), a), [x1_start x2_start], [], [], [], [], [], [], @(x) mycon(x(1), x(2), a, b));
x1 = x(1)
x2 = x(2)
```

with `mycon` defined as:

```
% C <= 0 and Ceq == 0
function [C, Ceq] = mycon(x1, x2, a, b)
    [y1, y2, y3] = f1(x1, x2, a);
    C = y1 - f2(x1, x2, y2, y3, b);
    Ceq = [];
end
```

and `x1_start` and `x2_start` the starting values for `x1` and `x2` in the iterative solver used by Matlab.

*Please take a look at the matlab documentation and examples for more information.*

Comment: Thank you! One question: how does Matlab know that, when writing `fmincon(@(x) f1(x(1), x(2), a),...)`, it has to minimize wrto `x(1), x(2)` only the first output `y1` of `f1`?

Comment: Because `fmincon` expects only one return argument. Matlab automatically discards extra return arguments if you do not need them, i.e. `y1 = f1(x1, x2, a)` will indeed store the first returned argument to `y1`.