# objective function for fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization

I need to maximize the following objective function in Matlab:

```
mean (a*I'*x1+b*(ones(1,24)-I)'*x1)-mean((a*(ones(1,24)-I)'*y1)+(b*I'*y1))
```

I made two .m file:

1. In the `objfun.m` file I defined the objective function as:

   ```
   function f = objfun(x)
   f = mean (a*I'*x1+b*(ones(1,24)-I)'*x1)-mean((a*(ones(1,24)-I)'*y1)+(b*I'*y1));
   ```
2. In the second (main) .m file I have my parameters and calculations for a, b and I and also below constraints and fmincon:

   ```
   lb = [0,0];
   ub = [10,10];
   x0 = [1,2];
   [x,fval] = fmincon(@objfun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)
   ```

When I run the program I get below error for fmincon:

> Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.

Would you please advise how can I fix this problem? Is there anything wrong with my objective function, as it is a function of `x1` and `y1` but I have `objfun(x)` only? Or do I call the function wrongly?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your objective function definition is not correct, i.e. you should define all your variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constrained minimization in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464008/constrained-minimization-in-matlab)

Comment: You didn't define `a`, `I`, `x1`, `b`, and `y1`

Comment: I defined a and b in my main.m file which are 1x24 vectors with constant values. x1 and y1 are defined as x1 = sym('x', [1 24]); y1 = sym('y', [1 24]); but still fmincon does not work. Also I tried with changing lb, ub,x0 dimensions to 24x1 vectors, but still I get the same error.